# Setup Github actions to build and deploy java code on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, github-actions

I have been trying to make Github actions to setup CI/CD for aws ec2 machine. I tried working with aws actions i.e. https://github.com/aws-actions but it only talks about deploying to ECS or by using Codebuild.

Is it possible to do this with Github actions alone? Steps which I am trying to do are:
1) build with maven
2) Deploy to ec2

I am new to this so any pointers would be helful.